# Class instances VS Interfaces VS generic objects - Performance

Tags: performance, class, object, interface

I'm creating mock data so that I can code the front end.

This data could be class instances or interfaces just plain old javascript objects. Personally I'd rather do it as javascript objects, because I don't like boiler plate code.

I need to make a decision about whether to use classes or interfaces or generic javascript objects for the mock data and also for the real data.

Which is more performant?

Here is an example of a class I'm currently deciding if should just be a  javascript object:

class:

```
export class Result {
  id: number;
  brand: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  rating: number;
  categories: string[];
  averagePrice: number;
  amount: string;
  reviews: Review[];
}
```

mock data:

```
import { Result } from './result';
export const RESULTS: Result[] = [
  { id: 11, 
    name: 'dairy free parmesan alternative original', 
    brand: "Angel Foods", 
    image: "result-images/dairy_free_parmesan_alternative_original.jpg",
    rating: 4.3,
    categories: ["dairy"],
    averagePrice: 6.60
  },
  { id: 12, 
    name: 'dairy free mozzarella alternative', 
    brand: "Angel Foods", 
    image: "result-images/dairy_free_mozzarella_alternative.jpg",
    rating: 3.9,
    categories: ["dairy"],
    averagePrice: 3.70
  },
  { id: 13, 
    name: 'dairy free tasty cheese sauce', 
    brand: "Angel Foods", 
    image: "result-images/dairy_free_tasty_cheese_sauce.jpg",
    rating: 3.7,
    categories: ["dairy", "condiment"],
    averagePrice: 5.50
  },
  { id: 14, 
    name: 'dairy free mild cheese mix', 
    brand: "Angel Foods", 
    image: "result-images/dairy_free_mild_cheese_mix.jpg",
    rating: 4.4,
    categories: ["dairy", "TV dinner"],
    averagePrice: 4.86,
    amount: "400g"
  },
  { id: 15, 
    name: 'sugar free dark chocolate salted caramel', 
    brand: "alpro", 
    image: "result-images/sugar_free_dark_chocolate_salted_caramel.png",
    rating: 4.2,
    categories: ["dessert", "Baking"],
    averagePrice: 4.32,
    amount: "400g"
  },
  { id: 16, 
    name: 'drink for professionals', 
    brand: "Alpro", 
    image: "result-images/alpro_drink_for_professional.jpg",
    rating: 2.1,
    categories: ["beverage"],
    averagePrice: 3.50,
    amount: "400g"
  },
  { id: 17, 
    name: 'custard', 
    brand: "alpro", 
    image: "result-images/alpro_custard.jpg",
    rating: 4.9,
    categories: ["dairy", "baking", "dessert"],
    averagePrice: 4.50,
    amount: "400g"
  },
  { id: 18, 
    name: 'coconut dessert', 
    brand: "alpro", 
    image: "result-images/alpro_coconut_dessert.jpg",
    rating: 3.1,
    categories: ["dairy", "baking", "dessert"],
    averagePrice: 6.50,
    amount: "400g"
  },
  { id: 19, 
    name: 'creamy caramel', 
    brand: "alpro", 
    image: "result-images/alpro_creamy_caramel.jpg",
    rating: 4.7,
    categories: ["dairy", "dessert"],
    averagePrice: 6.50,
    amount: "400g"
  },
  { id: 20, 
    name: 'dairy free sour cream alternative', 
    brand: "Angel Foods", 
    image: "result-images/dairy_free_sour_cream_alternative.jpg",
    rating: 4.5,
    categories: ["dairy", "condiment"],
    averagePrice: 4.8,
    amount: "400g"
  }
];
```

Meaning I could get rid of the result class and make it a JSON object, it would be a lot faster long term when I'm creating less classes to just hold objects that could be JSON or javascript objects. So is there a performance downfall by getting rid of classes/interfaces and using JSON objects?

From [reading a bit about performance](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/), it seems like if you let the compiler know **what the object is**, it'll perform better. This example is with an array but i get the feeling it is also true for objects. EG:

```
// Here V8 can see that you want a 4-element array containing numbers:
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// Don't do this:
a = []; // Here V8 knows nothing about the array
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
     a.push(i);
}
```

I'm guessing that this is because the compiler doesn't need to leave lots of space available for the object in memory since it knows what is coming. Which would mean a class instance is faster than a javascript object of no class.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is mock a server response I would suggest using an interface not a class.

```
export interface IResult {
  id: number;
  brand: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  rating: number;
  categories: string[];
  averagePrice: number;
  amount: string;
  reviews: Review[];
}
```

import { IResult } from './interfaces/entities/result';

```
export const RESULTS: IResult [] = [
  { id: 11, 
    name: 'dairy free parmesan alternative original', 
    brand: "Angel Foods", 
    image: "result-images/dairy_free_parmesan_alternative_original.jpg",
    rating: 4.3,
    categories: ["dairy"],
    averagePrice: 6.60
  }
  // ...
];
```

An HTTP API is an "Application programming interface" as you can guess by its name, it is an **interface** and in TypeScript you can define it using interfaces.

Comment: I will be using it for the real data as well. However this works well for the real data too. I was just wondering if there is anything wrong with not even having a class or interface, and using generic objects because it is less code. In terms of performance mainly.

Comment: If you don't have a class or interface the compiler will not be able to catch some errors. I would recommend to use a class or interface. If you are going to create instances of a class (invoke `new X()`) then use a class. If you are just going to get the instances from the server side then use an interface.